# 3Sum Why this O(nlogn) solution doesn't work?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, correctness-proof, search-problem

I have been doing LeetCode and tackled the problem of the 3Sum and first I tried to do a O(nlogn) solution and after seeing the proposed solution I see that the solution is $O(n^2)$ or $O(n^2 \times \log n)$ and not only that but the problem is a highly researched topic so I don't think I found a better solution but can't see why my approach wouldn't work, can use help to figure it out.

The problem is the following
Find three numbers in an array such that $a + b + c = t$,
the [LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum-closest/) is slightly different in which you need to find the closest sum.

My code is the following:

1. Sort the array.
2. Start with two pointers `i=0` and `j= last element of array`
3. Use binary search between `i` and `j` to find `m` such that `arr[m] == target - arr[i] - arr[j]`, if such `m` doesn't exist return `m` such that `arr[m]` is the closest.
4. If `arr[i] + arr[m] + arr[j] == target` then your finished.
5. Otherwise if `arr[i] + arr[m] + arr[j] < target` then add 1 to `i` else subtract 1 form `j`.
6. Repeat 3 → 5 until `j - i == 2`
7. Return the best found `i,m,j`

The logic in step 5 is that if the solution found is less than the target then we should increase `i` such that our next guess is bigger.

Code:

```python
def binSearch(arr, s, e, t):
    m = (s + e) // 2
    r = m
    d = 9999
    while s <= e:
        m = (s + e) // 2
        if arr[m] == t:
            return m
        elif arr[m] > t:
            e = m - 1
        else:
            s = m + 1

        if d > abs(t - arr[m]):
            d = abs(t - arr[m])
            r = m
    return r


class Solution:
    def threeSumClosest(self, nums, target: int) -> int:
        nums.sort()

        s = 0
        e = len(nums) - 1
        minn = 999999
        t = ()
        while e - s >= 2:
            left = nums[s]
            right = nums[e]
            remaining = target - (left + right)
            m = binSearch(nums, s + 1, e - 1, remaining)
            middle = nums[m]
            r = left + middle + right

            # print("i's: ", (s,m,e))
            # print("values: ", (nums[s], nums[m], nums[e]))
            # print("r", r)
            # print("**************")

            if r == target:
                return r
            elif r < target:
                s += 1
            else:
                e -= 1

            if abs(target - r) < minn:
                minn = abs(target - r)
                t = r
        return t
```

Comment: Your approach is very similar to the quadratic time algorithm described on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM#Quadratic_algorithm) page for 3SUM. It might be helpful to see the analysis presented there.

Comment: Is not quite the same, very similar but not the same (I'm going to put my code so you can see it better), what they do is for every `i` they traverse all `j` from `i+2` to `len(arr)` and find the missing index by doing a B.S. between `i` and `j`.

Comment: In my case I only go through each index once. Most probably this is wrong and there is a case where this doesn't work but I can see when

Comment: For example in an array of size 5 the variables `i` and `j` goes through: (0,4), (0,3),(0,2), (1,4),(1,3),(2,4), and in my code it will only be (0,4), (1,4),(1,3), (1,2) - this is a posible case -. Wikipedia code will have (n*(n+1)/2) pairs and mine will have n pairs (note that n is the size of the array minus 2).

Comment: @nick.schachter I don't know if you saw the code, but I uploaded the wrong code but I've changed, sorry.

Comment: In the phrase *I see that the solution is $O(n^2)$* in the first sentence, I find it avoidably difficult to tell *which* solution this refers to. Can you formulate that more accessibly? In the post body, you can use LaTeX to linearise formulas, see the help (essentially, fence in-line formulas in single `$`, elaborate ones in double).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fails for, e.g., [1, 9, 55, 55, 100], t=111. The first iteration finds 110 and increases i to exclude 1 as a possibility, but the only solution, [1, 55, 55], needs 1.

The basic problem is that when you increase i or reduce j, you are assuming that the element you just advanced past is not needed -- that there exists some solution that does not include it. But this is not justified by anything, and it could well be that all solutions need that element.

A great way to test algorithm ideas like this is to write a small program that generates many small random inputs, and compare the result of your algorithm on each of them to the result of a known-correct brute-force approach.